# InDesign CC: adjusting page size to fit the content

Tags: adobe-indesign, page-layout

Is there a way to adjust the size so it fits the content I have in the page, or do I have to adjust the page size manually? Thanks

[image: screenshot]

Comment: @Johnware pointed this out in a  comment previously: http://indesignsecrets.com/introducing-multiple-page-sizes-in-indesign-cs5.php

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **Page Tool** (<kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>) to manually resize individual pages. I can't find any way to automatically fit the page to artwork like you can in Illustrator.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure why but it seems you have to hold Alt for the resize to actually work (as mentioned below by suzette, even though they got downvoted).

Answer (score 1):

Negative, you will have to adjust the page size (file> document setup) or you could just bleed your image of the edges?

Answer (score 1):

If you change the size of the page manually (File > Document Setup), it will change the size of all pages, not just this page. I'm going to approach this as if you are a super beginner (no problem with that) and you're dropping everything in as a single illustrator file. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Here are two things I'd advise:

- *Quick Solution:* Change the background color of the image media box to the same color as the background of your illustrator file.
- *Best Practice Solution:* Type everything directly in InDesign, bring in the background color separately, and import all the images as separate files. *But why?* Importing type from Illustrator can give you mixed results, importing the files separately will allow you to quickly edit your page with out switching programs, and your computer won't slow down while making these edits because its not constantly rendering huge files.

Best of luck!

Comment: If you change the paper size in the paper size options fold-out menu in the _Pages_ panel, however, it will only apply to the pages selected. (Not saying that's the best way of doing this necessarily, just that you can change page size individually.)

Answer (score 0):

when using the Shift P page tool you can hold down Option Alt key when clicking on the box to resize and it will stay the size you edited it to be.